# Change Date short to timestamp angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, date, timestamp

I have an angular2 app with this

```
dateMin: Date = new Date();
dateMax: Date = new Date();
```

in the html I have this

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <input matInput type="datetime"  [(ngModel)] = "dateMin" [value]="dateMin | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <input matInput type="datetime"  [(ngModel)] = "dateMax"  [value]="dateMax | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' ">
</mat-form-field>
```

but I want to change the `dateMin` and `dateMax` to `timestamp` when I press a button. How do I do that?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work

`[(ngModel)] = "dateMinTimeStamp"`
`[(ngModel)] = "dateMaxTimeStamp"`

and let the `value` as you have it - so you don't mutate the dateMin, dateMax